# Parsing nested SQL queries with parenthesized predicates using pyparsing

Tags: pyparsing

I'm trying to parse nested queries of the form that contains predicates with parentheses. Example:

```
query = '(A LIKE "%.something.com" AND B = 4) OR (C In ("a", "b") AND D Contains "asdf")'
```

I've tried many of the answers/examples I've seen but without getting them to work, and this is what I have come up with so far that almost(?) works:

```
from pyparsing import *

r = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!"#$%&\'*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~'

any_keyword = CaselessKeyword("AND") | CaselessKeyword("OR")

non_keyword = ~any_keyword + Word(r)

expr = infixNotation(originalTextFor(non_keyword[1, ...]),
                     [
                         (oneOf("AND OR", caseless=True, asKeyword=True), 2, opAssoc.LEFT)
                     ])
```

Then, running `expr.parseString(query).asList()` returns only:

```
[['A LIKE "%.something.com"', 'AND', 'B = 4']]
```

without the rest of the query.
As far as I understand, this is due to the `C In ("a", "b")` part, since there are parentheses there.

Is there a way to "disregard" parentheses inside the predicates so that parsing returns the expected answer:

```
[[['A LIKE "%.something.com"', 'AND', 'B = 4'], 'OR', ['C In ("a", "b")', 'AND', 'D Contains "asdf"']]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to pyparsing! You've made some good headway from following other examples, but let's back up just a bit.

`infixNotation` is definitely the right way to go here, but there are many more operators in this expression than just `AND` and `OR`.  These are all sub-expressions in your input string:

```
A LIKE "%.something.com"
B = 4
C in ("a", "b")
D contains "asdf"
```

Each of these is its own binary expression, with operators "LIKE", "=", "in" and "contains". Also, your operands can be not only identifiers, but quoted strings, a collection of quoted strings, and numbers.

I like your intuition that this is a logical expression of terms, so let's define 2 levels of infixNotations:

1. an expression of column or numeric "arithmetic" (using '=', "LIKE", etc.)
2. an expression of terms defined by #1, combined with logical NOT, AND, and OR operators

If we call #1 a `column_expr`, #2 would look similar to what you have already written:

```
expr = infixNotation(column_expr,
                     [
                         (NOT, 1, opAssoc.RIGHT),
                         (AND, 2, opAssoc.LEFT),
                         (OR, 2, opAssoc.LEFT),
                     ])
```

I've added NOT as a reasonable extension to what you have now - most logical expressions include these 3 operators. Also, it is conventional to define them in this order of precedence, so that "X OR Y AND Z" eventually evaluates in the order "X OR (Y AND Z)", since AND has higher precedence than OR (and NOT is higher still).

#1 takes some more work, so I've written a little BNF for what we should expect for an individual operand for column_expr (I cannot recommend taking this step highly enough!):

```
identifier ::= one or more Words composed of printable letters (we may come back to this)
number ::= an integer or real number (we can use the one defined in pyparsing_common.number)
quotedString ::= (a quoted string like one define by pyparsing)
quotedString_list ::= '(' quotedString [',' quotedString]... ')'

# put identifier last, since it will match just about anything, and we want to try the other
# expressions first
column_operand ::= quotedString | quotedString_list | number | identifier
```

Then a column_expr will be an `infixNotation` using these column_operands:

```
ppc = pyparsing_common
LPAR, RPAR = map(Suppress, "()")
# use Group to keep these all together
quotedString_list = Group(LPAR + delimitedList(quotedString) + RPAR)

column_operand = quotedString | quotedString_list | ppc.number | identifier
column_expr = infixNotation(column_operand,
                            [
                                (IN | CONTAINS, 2, opAssoc.LEFT),
                                (LIKE, 2, opAssoc.LEFT),
                                ('=', 2, opAssoc.LEFT),
                            ])
```

If you find you have to add other operators like "!=", most likely you will add them in to column_expr.

Some other notes:

- You probably want to remove ' and " from `r`, since they should really be handled as part of the quoted strings
- As your list of keywords grows, you will find it easier to define them using something like this:

  ```
    AND, OR, NOT, LIKE, IN, CONTAINS = keyword_exprs = list(map(CaselessKeyword, """
        AND OR NOT LIKE IN CONTAINS
        """.split()))
    any_keyword = MatchFirst(keyword_exprs)
  ```

  Then you can reference them more easily as I have done in the code above.
- Write small tests first before trying to test the complex query you posted. Nice work in including many of the variations of operands. Then use `runTests` to run them all, like this:

  ```
    expr.runTests("""
                A LIKE "%.something.com"
                B = 4
                C in ("A", "B")
                D CONTAINS "ASDF"
                (A LIKE "%.something.com" AND B = 4) OR (C In ("a", "b") AND D Contains "asdf")
                """)
  ```

With these changes, I get this for your original query string:

```
[[['A', 'LIKE', '"%.something.com"'], 'AND', 'B = 4'], 'OR', [['C', 'IN', ['"a"', '"b"']], 'AND', ['D', 'CONTAINS', '"asdf"']]]
```

Hmmm, I'm not keen on a term that looks like `'B = 4'`, now that we are actually parsing the sub expressions. I suspect it is because your definition of identifier is a little too aggressive. If we cut it back to just `~any_keyword + Word(alphas, r)`, forcing a leading alpha character and without the `[1, ...]` for repetition, then we get the better-looking:

```
[[['A', 'LIKE', '"%.something.com"'], 'AND', ['B', '=', 4]], 'OR', [['C', 'IN', ['"a"', '"b"']], 'AND', ['D', 'CONTAINS', '"asdf"']]]
```

If in fact you *do* want these sub-expressions to be retained as they were found in the original, and just break up on the logical operators, then you can just wrap `column_expr` in `originalTextFor` as you used before, giving:

```
[['A LIKE "%.something.com"', 'AND', 'B = 4'], 'OR', ['C In ("a", "b")', 'AND', 'D Contains "asdf"']]
```

Good luck with your SQL parsing project!

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to reply in such detail, I really appreciate it!
Since the vocabulary of column_expr keywords (e.g., CONTAINS, IN, etc.) isn't completely known to me, I think I should take a simpler approach to the parsing, since I really only want  [what_is_left_of_AND/OR, AND/OR, what_is_right_of_AND/OR]. In the same vein as ['A LIKE "%.something.com"', 'AND', 'B = 4'].

Is there a way to just parse whatever is left/right of the AND/OR together, regardless of any character I see to the left or right (including spaces between words, quotes, etc.)?

Comment: I can sympathize, since things like numeric values, might actually be an arithmetic expression also (i.e., not just "4" but "4*sqrt(columnB)".  You may have some success in finding all the AND/OR/NOT keywords using something like `re.finditer(r"\b(AND|OR|NOT)\b", query, re.I)`, and then work from those locations to reconstruct the respective operands. Unfortunately, grouping with parentheses can make analysis difficult. But its an idea.